# Prism Change sort order of modules

Tags: prism

i'm upfrading (rewrite) a application from Prism 5.0 to 7.1.0.431
Here i'm looking for a way to set a modul as startmodul and, change the order of initialization of Moduls.
I know how to do this in Prism 5.0 but have no idea how it works in 7.xxx.
Thanks
Peter

Comment: What prevents you from using the Prism 5 solution? And why do you need to specify load order in the first place?

Comment: I agree with @Haukinger, do what you can to not care about the load order.  The only time that I have messed with that is when composing a UI from the loaded modules, which depending on the load order would change how the UI looks (order of menus, etc)  You can mess with the other using module dependencies, but it gets complicated as the number of modules increase, and I hate putting in fake dependencies.  Better to fix the reason they need to load in a specific order,

Comment: @RobGoodwin I'd rather use a sort hint for the menu items than rely on module load order :-)